# Finite sum of powers of $\log(j)$

Tags: logarithms, closed-form

Is there any closed-form for:

$\sum_{j=1}^{n}[\log(j)]^k$, for integer $k$?

Perhaps we should start real simple, so how about this one: $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\log^2(j)$

The importance of having this closed-form is that it's related to the Zeta function through a method I devised.

Comment: Do you need a bound or an exact closed form?

Comment: @Susan_Math123 closed form, I dislike bounds.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there is a closed form (except for $k=1$). That said, you can have good estimates. For instance, using integration by parts (for sums),
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \log (k) \approx n\log(n)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \log^2 (k) \approx n\log^2(n)$$

Comment: I don't like approximations, but thank you.

Comment: @JRS.: Sometimes approximations are all you can get. In this case, the special functions necessary to produce a closed form are pretty complicated.

Comment: You can get more terms in the asymptotic expansion using the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula: $$ \sum_{k=1}^n\log(k)^2=n\log(n)^2-2n\log(n)+2n+\frac12\log(n)^2+C +\frac{\log(n)}{6n}+O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^3}\right) $$ where $C=\frac{\gamma^2}2-\frac{\pi^2}{24}-\frac12\log(2\pi)^2+\gamma_1$, as shown in Mariusz Iwaniuk's answer.

Answer (score 1):

A long comment:

$$\sum _{j=1}^n \log ^k(j)=\\\sum _{j=1}^n \left(\underset{t\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial ^kj^t}{\partial
   t^k}\right)=\\\underset{t\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial ^k}{\partial t^k}\left(\sum _{j=1}^n j^t\right)=\\\underset{t\to
   0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial ^kH_n^{(-t)}}{\partial t^k}=\\\underset{t\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial ^k(-\zeta
   (-t,1+n)+\zeta (-t))}{\partial t^k}$$

For `k=2`:

$$\color{red}{\sum _{j=1}^n \log ^2(j)}=\\\underset{t\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial ^2(-\zeta (-t,1+n)+\zeta (-t))}{\partial t^2}=\\\underset{t\to
   0}{\text{lim}}\left(\zeta ''(-t)-\zeta ^{(2,0)}(-t,1+n)\right)=\color{red}{\\\frac{\gamma ^2}{2}-\frac{\pi ^2}{24}-\frac{1}{2} \log ^2(2
   \pi )+\gamma _1-\zeta ^{(2,0)}(0,1+n)}$$

Mathematica code:

```
HoldForm[Limit[D[-Zeta[-t, 1 + n] + Zeta[-t], {t, 2}], t -> 0] == 
Limit[Derivative[2][Zeta][-t] - Derivative[2, 0][Zeta][-t, 1 + n], t -> 0] == 
EulerGamma^2/2 - Pi^2/24 - (1/2)*Log[2*Pi]^2 + StieltjesGamma[1] - Derivative[2, 0][Zeta][0, 1 + n]]
```

Where:

$H_n^{(-t)}$ is  harmonic number of order t,

[$\zeta ''(-t)$](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1985-44-169/S0025-5718-1985-0771044-5/) is second derivative of Riemann zeta function.

$\zeta (-t,n+1)$ is generalized Riemann zeta function,

$\gamma$ is Euler's constant,

$\gamma _1$ is Stieltjes constant,

[$\zeta ^{(2,0)}(0,n+1)$](https://digitalcommons.wku.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2093&context=theses) is second derivative of generalized Riemann zeta function.